# How can I pass an object with an embedded object from JavaScript (jQuery/ajax) to Python (Flask)?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, flask

I am attempting to pass structured data from a web page to a flask handler, but I am getting key errors.

In the web page's JavaScript, I have an object that has two elements, one a value, the other an object.

The problem is on the Flask/Python side.   I can get the first element (`"cid"`) with this:

```
print request.form ["cid"]
```

That works.  But, I can't access or get to any of the att(ribute) values (`"att"`).

So, this, `request.form ["att"]` returns `KeyError: 'att'`

I am able to access `request.form["att[sw1]"]` but this is flattening my data type.

I'd like to get the att elements as a list or dictionary so that I can loop through them in my application.  I essentially want `request.form["att"]["sw1"]` or `request.form.att["sw1"]`.

```
   var controllerData = {
              sw1  : $('#sw1').val(),
              sw2  : $('#sw2').val(),
              sw3  : $('#sw3').val(),
              sw4  : $('#sw4').val()}

   var updateData = {cid : 1, att: controllerData };

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:  "/SetSettings",
     data: updateData,
     success: function(d) { },
     error: function(d) {alert('Error saving settings!');},
     dataType: "json"
   });
```

Comment: Of course I make progress right after I post!  first, I had to create my composite object in the web page javascript:  var updateData = {cid : 1, att: JSON.stringify(controllerData) },   then on the Flask/Python side I needed to convert the att string into a dictionary:  attributes = json.loads(request.form["att"]).    This solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You must serialize your data object to string with [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url:  "/SetSettings",
   data: JSON.stringify(updateData),
   success: function(d) { },
   error: function(d) {alert('Error saving settings!');},
   dataType: "json"
});
```

PS: Some object, e.g. `window` or object containing cyclic dependencies cannot be serialized this way

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json'` also may be needed